# Current conservation in presence of SSB: weak currents

Tags: standard-model, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance, weak-interaction

The Standard Model SSB breaks the $SU(2)_W \times U(1)_Y$ to $U(1)_{EM}$. The Noether currents associated to the unbroken group are $J_{a,\mu} = \bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \frac{\tau_a}{2} P_L \psi $ and $J_{\mu} = \bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu  P_L \psi $, (where $\tau_a$ are the Pauli matrices and $\psi$ is an isospin fermionic doublet like $(\nu_\mu , \mu^-)$).

Even if the symmetry group is spontaneously broken, the currents should still satisfy $\partial^\mu J_\mu = 0$.
Anyway this seems to be not true. Take for example the tree level process of muon decay $\mu^- \rightarrow e^- \bar{\nu}_{e} \nu_\mu$, that happens by $W^-$ exchange. The internal bosonic propagator contains terms  like $q_\alpha q_\beta$, that gives a contribute that goes as (I write only the muon piece) $ \bar{u}_{\nu_\mu} \gamma^{\alpha} q_\alpha P_L u_\mu = m_\mu \bar{u}_{\nu_\mu} P_R u_\mu $. This follows immediately from the Dirac equation $ p_\alpha \gamma^\alpha u(p) = m \, u(p)$ and $\{\gamma_5,\gamma^\alpha\}=0$. This suggests $ \partial^\mu j_\mu = \mathcal{O}(m) \ne 0$.

The situation is totally different for QED, where, in fact, the $q_\alpha q_\beta$ terms drop out due to gauge invariance. I think the key to the story is that the particles in the same vertex have different masses, whereas in QED must have the same mass being the interaction flavour diagonal (think at the process $e^+ e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$).

To conclude, which is true (and why)? $\partial^\mu J_\mu = 0$ or $\partial^\mu J_\mu = \mathcal{O}(m)$?

Comment: Yes, really thank you. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The gauged currents of the Standard model are always conserved***, otherwise they could not consistently couple to gauge fields.

The missing Higgs-doublet piece of your currents is crucial for current conservation on-shell, as the mass of fermions arises out of the Yukawa terms, coupling Higgs to fermion doublets. Its corresponding charge rotates fermions and bosons in synchrony, to achieve invariance. Separate fermion and boson pieces of currents are not isolated in conservation.

(Besides, your weak hypercharge fermion current piece is quite wrong: weak hypercharge has a right-chiral piece as well, for all charged fermions! The SU(2) piece is correct, but it needs its Higgs counterpart for conservation.)

Even though SSB is a resolutely QM phenomenon, the mechanics in the current conservation is basically classical, implicit in the deceptively innocuous *language* of coordinates, set for quantization, and can be surveyed in the Lagrangian "before" SSB, in the unshifted or shifted field coordinates--a change of language should not matter, and is only relevant when you inspect the vacuum.

But the plethora of fields and the Higgs mechanism of the SM are overkill. All you need is the setup for chiral SSB elucidated in the legendary [σ model](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02859738) of 1960, a must-must-must read,  which essentially underlies half of the logic of the SM; the particular SSB stunt is apocryphally attributed to Feynman.

I illustrate the point by vulgarizing it further to just a  schematic chiral O(2) model, ever oblivious of inessential normalizations and signs, etc.: The point is more important than the details.

$${\cal L}\propto i\bar \psi \partial \!\! / \psi -{m\over v} \bar \psi (\sigma +i\gamma_5 \pi)\psi + \partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma + \partial_\mu \pi \partial^\mu \pi - \frac{m_\sigma^2}{4v^2}(\sigma^2+\pi^2-v^2)^2. 
$$
It is invariant, $
\delta {\cal L} = 0$, under the chiral symmetry
$$
\delta \pi= -\epsilon \sigma , \qquad \delta \sigma = \epsilon \pi,\\
\delta \psi = {i\epsilon \gamma_5\over 2}~ \psi.
$$

The Noether chiral current is
$$
J_\mu \propto \bar \psi \gamma_5 \gamma_\mu \psi +2(\pi\partial_\mu \sigma -\sigma \partial_\mu \pi).
$$
Check that it is on-shell (e.o.m.) conserved, as it should be. Observe how the coordination between fermionic and bosonic components is necessary for conservation. The corresponding interaction term is the group invariance linchpin.

Now, in anticipation of quantization, one may rewrite all this
in terms of shifted coordinates, $\sigma = v+ \sigma'$,
$${\cal L}\propto i\bar \psi \partial \!\! / \psi - m \bar \psi \psi-{m\over v} \bar \psi (\sigma' +i\gamma_5 \pi)\psi + \partial_\mu \sigma' \partial^\mu \sigma' + \partial_\mu \pi \partial^\mu \pi - m_\sigma^2 \sigma'^2  \\ - \frac{m_\sigma^2}{v}\sigma' (\sigma'^2+\pi^2 )     - \frac{m_\sigma^2}{4v^2}(\sigma'^2+\pi^2 )^2. 
$$
with conserved chiral current, (we only changed variables, after all!)
$$
J_\mu \propto \bar \psi \gamma_5 \gamma_\mu \psi -2v \partial_\mu \pi +2(\pi\partial_\mu \sigma ' -\sigma ' \partial_\mu \pi).
$$

The middle term on the r.h.s. is the celebrated "mother-of-PCAC" term for the massless Goldstone mode π upon quantization. Its (PB) action in the charge is to basically *shift* the  π, the key nonlinear action involved.  But, here, too, the current is conserved, less transparently so in these new shifted coordinates.

From this simplest of all models you may answer all your questions, and, of course, replicate the rigmarole for the messier SM currents. Ever conserved.